# Inheritance from non-protocol type 'PFObject'

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, back4app

I am getting this error `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'PFObject'` on Xcode with Swift while trying to create a Model, here is the code of the model:

```
import Foundation
import ParseSwift
import Parse
import SwiftUI

struct Category: ParseObject, PFObject {

    // Required properties from ParseObject protocol
    var originalData: Data?
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    // Custom fields for the contact's information
    var name: String = ""
    var cover: String = ""
    var color: String = ""
    var createdBy: String = ""
}

extension Category {
    init(name: String, cover: String, color: String, createdBy: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.cover = cover
        self.color = color
        self.createdBy = createdBy
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PFObject is a class, you cannot inherit struct from a class, only class from a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use [Parse-Swift](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift) and the [Parse Objective-C SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) at the same time which you shouldn't be doing. Your `ParseObject` is setup using Parse-Swift so assuming that's what you want to use, remove, `import Parse` and your Parse Object should look like:

```swift
import Foundation
import ParseSwift
import SwiftUI

struct Category: ParseObject {

    // Required properties from ParseObject protocol
    var originalData: Data?
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    // All Custom fields should be optional
    var name: String?
    var cover: String?
    var color: String?
    var createdBy: String?
}

extension Category {
    init(name: String, cover: String, color: String, createdBy: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.cover = cover
        self.color = color
        self.createdBy = createdBy
    }
}
```

Remove the `Parse` dependency completely from your project as `Parse-Swift` doesn't use or need it at all. The [playgrounds](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/tree/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages) in Parse-Swift show how to use the SDK correctly along with any imports that are needed to use the SDK.